# Ionic 4, Angular 7 reading in a local file

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I am trying to import or read in a local file in the latest Ionic 4, Angular 7.
I have tried both importing and using http.get (ionic-native) without success

For http.get I tried the following (http.get is working when retrieving files from a server):

```
this.http.get('assets/createdb1', {}, {}).then((response) => {
console.log(response.status);
console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data)); });
```

When I run it I receive the following error:

> There was an error with the request: java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: assets/createdb1

On the http.get I have tried file://assets/createdb1  and got a similar error.

I also tried importing it into my list.page.ts file

```
 import createdbsql from 'assets/createdb1';
```

and received

> error TS2307: Cannot find module 'assets/createdb1'

I tried '../assets/createdb1'  and '../../assets/createdb1' and received the same error.

Any ideas on the correct way to import the file ?

Comment: What kind of data/file is that you want to import? I am asking this because depending on data, you can use json file or model.ts.

Comment: In my Ionic 3 app they  were sql statements, however I have converted it to a JSON array (of SQL statements). The next step will be to use SQLitePorter to create a database.

Comment: To import data from local json use import * as data from './example.json';
But also you need to create definition file and write in it :declare module "*.json" {
    const value: any;
    export default value;
  }     more about it on link https://hackernoon.com/import-json-into-typescript-8d465beded79

Comment: Bognar Thank you, working from the  link I found I needed to add  in tsconfig.json compilerOptions  `  "resolveJsonModule": true, `  ` "esModuleInterop" : true` and the import statement  `import createdbsql from '../../assets/createdb.json';`

Comment: just to make it clearer add in  tsconfig.json `compilerOptions { "resolveJsonModule":true, "esModuleInterop" :true` }